# Add custom css class for the search page filter

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-hook

I'm trying to add a custom CSS class for the search page that uses WooCommerce Product Search.

Search pages path is like:

```
domain.com/shop/ixwpss=3&title=0&excerpt=0&content=0&categories=0&attributes=0&tags=1&sku=0&v=a3420e5a4c03
```

When I search for the number 3 that represents the tag for products.

I managed to add the class for the whole shop, with the following function but I want to add only for the search page. Can someone help me?

```
add_filter( 'body_class', 'add_body_classes' );

function add_body_classes( $classes ) {

   global $post;

     if ( is_shop() ) 

     $classes[] = 'search'; 
   
   return $classes;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please update the code like below

```
add_filter( 'body_class', function( $classes ) { 
 if ( is_shop() ) {return array_merge( $classes, array( 'class-name' ) );}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the search page is using the `archive-product.php`

If you are using a WooCommerce compatible theme then you have to go in your `themes folder -> woocommerce` and find the `archive-product.php`. If the override file does not exists then go to `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/archive-product.php`

**And a if statement to check if is search or not like below:**

```
if ( is_search() ) {
    <body class="your-class">
} else {
    <body class="regular-class">
    // the content that is already in that file (archive-product.php)
}
```

*if the part (body class in your case) is not there you have to locate it and do the same  (probably it's in your `header.php`)

Comment: In archive-product.php I have something like this                                                                                                       
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;
get_header( 'shop' );
// Add Custom Shop Content if set
if(is_shop() && flatsome_option('html_shop_page_content') && ! $wp_query->is_search() && $wp_query->query_vars['paged'] < 1 ){
    echo do_shortcode('<div class="shop-page-content">'.flatsome_option('html_shop_page_content').'</div>');
} else {
 wc_get_template_part( 'layouts/category', flatsome_option( 'category_sidebar' ) );
}
get_footer( 'shop' );